# TSQL: finding unique entries in a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unique, aggregate

Consider a table or CTE structured like this:

```
Name    Num
----    ----
Abc     12
Abc     12
XYZ     70
XYZ     80
XYZ     85
Bar     50
Bar     55
Foo     44
Foo     44
Baz     88
```

The requirement is to determine the **Name** where **multiple different** Nums exist.

The desired resultset is

```
Name   
----
XYZ     
Bar
```

What TSQL statement would you use to derive this resultset?

Update: indeed there could be 2+ entries for a given Name.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than two XYZ occurrencies in the table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assumes no NULLs in Num column

```
select
   Name
from
   MySetObject
group by
   name
having
   min(num) <> max(num)
    -- also COUNT(DISTINCT Num) > 1 achieves the same
```

Comment: +1, was just going to post the `COUNT(DISTINCT Num)` version you just edited in

Comment: ;-( you snooze, you lose.  I'm sure the execution plan would be almost identical